# Integrable of almost complex structure

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

First, what is the induced complex multiplication in $TM\times  C$ ?

Second, is there some example  ?

Picture below is from Tian's *Canonical Metrics in Kahler Geometry*.

> [image]

Comment: I do not see why does he need $TM\times {\mathbb C}$ (I think, he actually meant the complexification of the tangent bundle $TM$).  The wikipedia explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold is standard (although, seemingly written by a physicist).

Comment: That's a typo: "Induced complex multiplication" is defined (on the second factor) in $TM \otimes \mathbf{C}$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  Could you explain what is the induced complex multiplication ? Just be the multiplication of the complex tangent bundle ?

Comment: $\alpha (v \otimes \beta) = v \otimes (\alpha\beta)$. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  So, I guess $J$ can be saw as some multiplication . For example, $J(v\otimes \beta)=v\otimes i\beta$. But I know little about complex manifold. And I don't know how the holomorphic structure induce a complex multiplication in $TM\otimes \mathbb C$ . If you have no time to explain it in detail , just tell me what book is about this . Thanks very much.

Comment: Actually, $J$ acts by $J(v \otimes \beta) = (Jv) \otimes \beta$. The details have surely been addressed elsewhere on Math.SE, but after a bit of searching I'm not finding a suitable reference....

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  Thanks too.